# How to turn a column of numbers into a list in a for loop

Tags: python

```
numbers = input("Enter more than 3 numbers:").split()

for i in numbers:
    numbers = int(i)
    print(numbers)
```

if the input is 1 2 3,
the output in the loop will be
1
2
3
.how do I get [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: Append `number` to a list, or use a list comprehension. The same way you make lists of anything.

Comment: `numbers` is a list of strings. `[int(i) for i in numbers]` returns a list of integers (see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter more than 3 numbers:").split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = input("Enter more than 3 numbers:")

alist = []

for i in numbers:
    alist.append(i)

print(alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to convert the elements of the list from `string` to `int`.

Another way to do this is with list comprehension so:

```
numbers = input("Enter more than 3 numbers:").split() #creates list from input

numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers] #converts i to an int for each i in the list numbers, and reassigns that new list to the variable numbers

print(numbers)
```